# How can I restore grub after switching from Windows 8 to 7 on a dual boot?

Tags: windows

I formerly had windows 7 without ubuntu. Now I upgraded it to windows 8..then I installed ubuntu 12.10 with live disk.

After installing it runs ok and I see a dual boot option in grub menu. Now sometimes I log in to windows 8 for some tasks. After some days I find windows 8  not interesting and I want to reinstall windows 7...now to do that I have to boot windows 7 disc from my dvd drive just like before..

My problem is if I want to reinstall windows it will not again show the grub menu and will directly go the windows desktop... So how can I get back that boot option menu (grub) to log in to ubuntu after reinstalling windows?

Comment: Hi Hunter. Welcome to AskUbuntu. Did you check this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204828/installed-windows-7-with-ubuntu-12-and-grub-isnt-there?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix that, 
1) After installing Win7, try re-installing grub from live ubuntu.
(or)
2) Use Easy BCD from Win7 to bring back grub entries.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: please explain further..i dont seem to understand..explain the process