# Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, asus, bios

I just built my first PC, and I am definitely getting Windows 7(or 8) however I don't have the money to just go get Windows till next week. My question is do I need to have windows first? If I install Ubuntu before Windows can I still install Windows after? All I have right now is the Asus system BIOS and I have never done this yet. really appreciate your time and answers you guys can provide for me. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12 and grub isn't there?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204828/installed-windows-7-with-ubuntu-12-and-grub-isnt-there)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Linux first and after that Windows.

I am not sure if windows is now capable of detecting already installed boot loaders. When windows is overwriting the linux bootloader you have to start your linux system from a live cd and reinstall the bootloader. Linux bootloaders can detect other operating systems and can start them.

Comment: Ok so I can install Linux first thats great. So when I install Windows are you saying its going to wipe Ubuntu from the hard drive. The plan is to partition 100gb for Ubuntu and 400 for Windows. Also my build does not have a disk drive so I plan to use a 16gb flash drive to install the OS on the harddrive. Currently all I have is the Asus BIOS running. Sorry for the very noobish questions I am new to not only Linux but PC building as well.

Comment: After installing Windows (I suggest creating a NTFS with GParted before) you boot your Ubuntu Live stick (I don't guess Windows will recognise/accept GRUB) and use it to rebuild GRUB.